# Weekly time series plot in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to create a plot of weekly data. Though this is not the exact problem I am having it illustrates it well. Basically imagine you want to make a plot of 1,2,....,7 for for 7 weeks from Jan 1 2015. So basically my plot should just be a line that trends upward but instead I get 7 different lines.  I tried the code (and some other to no avail). Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
startDate = "2015-01-01"
endDate = "2015-02-19"
y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
tsy=ts(y,start=as.Date(startDate),end=as.Date(endDate))
plot(tsy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are plotting both the time and y together as individual plots.

Instead use:

```
plot(y)
lines(y)
```

Also, create a date column based on the specifics you gave which will be a time series. From here you can add the date on the x-axis to easily see how your variable changes over time.

Comment: Thank you! So simple but it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier I think your first step should be to create a (xts) time series object (install/load the xts-package), then it is a piece of cake to plot, subset or do whatever you like with the series.

Build your vector of dates as a sequence with start/end date:

```
seq( as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=7)
```

and your data vector:  `1:7`

a one-liner builds and plots the above time series object:

```
plot(as.xts(1:7,order.by=seq( as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=7)))
```